# Good reference book for statistics in medicine

Tags: references, biostatistics

I am looking for a good reference book for applying statistics to medical problems.  I am interested in a practical book that describes concepts including statistical power, tests for comparing groups, and regression analysis in the context of medical problems.

Answer (score 3):

This book is really good, though very introductory: **What is a p-value anyway?** by Vickers. He draws on his experience as a medical researcher. Perhaps it provides a good high level of info and helps with the intuition side of things.

However, I know you asked for more of a reference book. I have heard good things about these 3 books from several different colleagues:

1. **Principles of Biostatistics** by Pagano
2. **Optimal Design of Experiments: A Case Study Approach** by Goos and Jones
3. **Practical Statistics for Medical Research** by Altman

Answer (score 2):

*Biostatistics: The Bare Essentials*, 4th Edition by Geoffrey R. Norman and David L. Streiner covers the areas that you named. If nothing else, it is funny and not dry reading.

The 4th edition covers more about sample size calculation than the 3rd edition. Here is a [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1607951789) to Amazon.